# Using sql, how can I create a table of all direct and indirect connections that exist in a network of gossipers?

Tags: sql, recursion, google-bigquery

I have a table with gossip_from and gossip_too pairings and my goal is to identify gossip circles that are above 4 people. To do so, I need to create a table with all gossip_from and gossip_too connections both directly and indirectly related. I believe I'd need to use recursive joins, but am stuck on how to accomplish this. Any ideas?

INPUT TABLE

| Gossip From | Gossip To |
| --- | --- |
| m19824 | s239817 |
| m53153 | s239817 |
| m53153 | s2394 |
| m9812 | s2394 |
| m9812 | s9860 |
| m79976 | s9860 |
| m79976 | s4231 |
| m245133 | s982124 |
| m245133 | s198274 |
| m245133 | s2308742 |
| m79497 | s2308742 |

DESIRED OUTPUT TABLE

| Gossip From | Gossip To |
| --- | --- |
| m19824 | s239817 |
| m19824 | s2394 |
| m19824 | s9860 |
| m19824 | s4231 |
| m53153 | s239817 |
| m53153 | s2394 |
| m53153 | s9860 |
| m53153 | s4231 |
| m9812 | s239817 |
| m9812 | s2394 |
| m9812 | s9860 |
| m9812 | s4231 |
| m79976 | s239817 |
| m79976 | s2394 |
| m79976 | s9860 |
| m79976 | s4231 |
| m245133 | s982124 |
| m245133 | s198274 |
| m245133 | s2308742 |
| m79497 | s982124 |
| m79497 | s198274 |
| m79497 | s2308742 |

I'm trying to do this on a larger dataset. I tried to do regular joins, but it didn't create all the connections needed. Especially if there is a long chain of gossipers.

```
select distinct a.gossip_from, c.gossip_to
from gossip_pairs a   
left join gossip_pairs b on a.gossip_to=b.gossip_to
left join gossip_pairs c on b.gossip_from=c.gossip_from
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help. I haven't tried is myself but it seems correct logically to me.

```
WITH RECURSIVE all_gossip_connections AS (
  -- Base case: Direct connections from the input table
  SELECT gossip_from, gossip_to
  FROM input_table

  UNION ALL

  -- Recursive step: Find indirect connections by joining the input table with the current results
  SELECT agc.gossip_from, it.gossip_to
  FROM input_table AS it
  JOIN all_gossip_connections AS agc
  ON it.gossip_from = agc.gossip_to
)

-- Final query to filter out circles with less than 5 people and remove duplicates
SELECT DISTINCT gossip_from, gossip_to
FROM all_gossip_connections
WHERE (gossip_from, gossip_to) IN (
  SELECT gossip_from, gossip_to
  FROM (
    SELECT gossip_from, COUNT(DISTINCT gossip_to) AS num_connections
    FROM all_gossip_connections
    GROUP BY gossip_from
  )
  WHERE num_connections >= 4
)
ORDER BY gossip_from, gossip_to;
```

- The query starts with a recursive table named `all_gossip_connections` that includes both direct and indirect connections.
- The base case of the table selects direct connections from the input table.
- The recursive step joins the input table with the current results on the condition that the gossip_from in the input table equals gossip_to in the current results. This finds indirect connections and keeps traversing until no new connections are found.
- The recursive step joins the input table with the current results on the condition that the gossip_from in the input table equals gossip_to in the current results. This finds indirect connections and keeps traversing until no new connections are found.